# SQL Server Up to x cells of data may have been dropped during insert from the following columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing a bulk csv data insert by "Import Flat File" at SQL Server 2019 Express.
After inserting, there's a pop-out warning message:

> Up to x cells of data may have been dropped during insert from the following columns

Is there a way I can know which row of cells have been dropped and what the reason might be to cause this warning?

Comment: refer to [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-to-prevent-possible-loss-of-data-microsoft-excel-cannot-shift-nonblank-cells-off-the-worksheet-416823da-bbaf-1f63-3317-2a5d6803bf39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no provision to check which data is dropped but the Reason for that warning most possibly due to sql server is assigning wrong data type for those column. To tackle that you manually assign best suitable data type for that column.